# Positioning: style and computed style have different values

Tags: css, pixel, computed-style

First post on this platform :)

I'm currently having an issue with percentage positioning. The style and the computed style are showing a different value for the top property of my element:

- the value I see in the computed style is in pixels instead of in % as defined in the stylesheet
- the value is different: if I replace the style with the computed style, the element moves down of about 40 pixels.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="img1" />
    <img id="img2" />
</div>

#container { position:relative; display:inline-block;}
#img1 { position:relative; }
#img2 { position:absolute; top:40% }
```

`img1` is 600px high. Since it has a relative positioning, `container` gets its height. So `container` is 600px high. If I do the math, top position of #img2 in pixels should be 240px. 
But computed style is giving me 280px. Why?

This thing happens for almost all children in my container and it is driving me nuts!

Does anyone have an idea of what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle):

> getComputedStyle() gives the final used values of all the CSS properties of an element.

Computed style values will always be absolute values as they represent the state of a given element *after* the browser has finished applying CSS.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/used_value

---

**Edit**

Now that you've provided code, I can answer your specific issue.

Set `display: block` on `#container` and your images.

The computed value is relative to the containing document, not to the immediate parent of the element. If you take a screenshot and measure the distance from the top of `#container` down to the top of `#img2` you should see that it's correctly 240px. However, the computed value of `top` for `#img2` won't necessarily be 240px.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KLv8v/). The blue rectangle is absolutely positioned at `top: 40%;` which correctly renders 240px down in its 600px container, but if you look at the computed value for `top` it'll report a different value because it's relative to the top of the viewport, which has margins set on the body.

Comment: Hi André, thanks for your help. How come can the computed value be different from the one I have in my style though? There is a 40-pixel difference between the absolute value and the percentage...

Comment: Because often authored value != computed value. The computed value in pixels represents the (absolute) calculated position of your relative authored value applied to the document. Did you notice that when you changed the authored value to 40px that the computed value may have also changed?

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. When I change the authored value to 40px, the computed value is 40px.

Comment: That's perfectly valid—I said it *may* have also changed. Without any code or demo of the specific issue you're having, it's impossible to predict.

Comment: I added display:block on #container and on my images, doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: That is crazy! How do I get the top position of #img2 in javascript then? Btw, setting the height of #container to 600px does the trick.

Comment: I think I've more than sufficiently answered your question, but you keep adding new criteria to it. If you're happy with my answer to your *original* question, please mark it as correct. Create a new question for any additional questions.

Comment: I still need a fix though :/ Setting the height of #container is kind of tedious.

Comment: Ok I just created a new question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867841/how-to-get-the-authored-style-properties-of-an-element

Comment: Did you see my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KLv8v/)? There's no height set on the container.