# How to get the authored style properties of an element?

Tags: jquery, css, computed-style

I am using jQuery to animate elements on my page.

In order to re-initialize the position of all my elements at the end, I need to get the authored properties of my elements, specified in % in my stylesheet.

I first used the `.css()` function but it is giving me the computed value, which I don't want. I am looking for the values I declared in the CSS (percent or pixels).

Any ideas on how to get that?

Comment: @CécileBoucheron: You'll have to record the original CSS values for each element before you animate the element via jQuery; I've recorded values by using data-attributes, but there are many ways you can go about it. Alternatively, if you can, animate by setting the values via `element.attr("style", "...")` as inline-style takes precedence over a class definition. Then you can access the original CSS value and use that value to re-initialize the position by setting the style `element.attr("style", "...")`

Comment: Thanks. All my styles are in my stylesheet though, so `attr('style')` isn't the solution :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `.position()` instead of `.css('top')` or `.css('left')`, then convert the values into percents.

Answer (score 0):

@CécileBoucheron

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emgee/ES9Yb/) and see if it gives you some idea on how you can approach your exact situation.

This isn't perfect, if you declared the original position using a % value, jQuery returns the element's pixel location so it likely won't be adequate if your design needs to be responsive.

An interesting thing to note, if your element is initially hidden - `display:none` - and before you show the element you record its original CSS declared position, you will get the %age value declared in the CSS style. Might work in your case?

Cheers!